# In Codeigniter REST_Controller $this->post('key'); is always null?

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

I'm getting a null result of $this->post('key'). I tried all the possible solutions and suggestions and none of them worked for me.

What I have tried is, var_dump($_POST) is giving null but when I tried var_dump($_REQUEST) I received the requested content including headers, sessions and the sent data thru POSTMAN. Also, tried the headers content-type: application-json. and still, nothing working for me. I had to investigate the core of the library and fetch out the post method and replace $this->_post_args = $_POST by $this->_post_args = $_REQUEST and offcourse it worked fine. However, this is not the right way.

$mobile = $this->post('mobile');

```
    if(!is_numeric($mobile) || strlen($mobile) != 10){
        $this->response(['status'=>$mobile, 'message' => 'Invalid Mobile Number, 10 digits are required'], REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

{
    "status": 'mobile number', // just to test the output
    "message": "Invalid Mobile Number, 10 digits are required"
}
but the actual is:
{
    "status": null,
    "message": "Invalid Mobile Number, 10 digits are required"
}

Comment: `$this->post()` isn't a function in codeigniter. it seems like you might be referencing an external library without explicitly mentioning it.

Comment: $this->post() is defined in REST_Controller where I'm extending my controller from it. You can get more details about this architecture from this link. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it out. The requester wasn't passing the data in the Request Body nor the Query String Parameters due to the post data was null.